# I cannot remove/install software due to some dependency issue

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm having difficulty trying to install/uninstall applications in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have this warning error that appears on my desktop in the form of a red icon with a line through it and it states:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: 'Error: BrokenCount > 0' — This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

I tried to repair automatically through ubuntu software center and I kept getting errors or it just didn't seem to work. Afterwards, I opened terminal and used **sudo apt-get check** command to see what the problem was and the results yielded:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjack-jackd2-0 : Breaks: libjack-jackd2-0:i386 (!= 1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1) but 1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1 is installed
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 : Breaks: libjack-jackd2-0 (!= 1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1) but 1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

After I ran **sudo apt-get -f install** (in an attempt to fix the issue at hand), I encountered the following errors/code:

```
okudaira@haru-kano:~$ sudo apt-get -f install

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libjack-jackd2-0
Suggested packages:
  jackd2
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libjack-jackd2-0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/197 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 181702 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libjack-jackd2-0 1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1 (using .../libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libjack-jackd2-0 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 './usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/buildinfo.gz' is different from the same file on the system
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_amd64.deb
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/locale: 0 KiB
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/man: 0 KiB
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/gnome/help: 0 KiB
localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/omf: 0 KiB

Total disk space freed by localepurge: 0 KiB

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The real problem I'm having is interpreting what is being stated. I'm fairly new to the ubuntu experience so I'm not very well-versed in the terminology and all the ins and outs.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my system? I can no longer install/remove any programs at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```bash
sudo apt-get clean
```

then try to install it again:

```bash
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I did that and then this error happened: `dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 './usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/buildinfo.gz' is different from the same file on the system
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.2-1precise1_amd64.deb`

Comment: I was able to figure it out, I ended up removing the package in question (/usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/buildinfo.gz) via `sudo rm /usr/share/doc/libjack-jackd2-0/buildinfo.gz` and then re-did the update.